# Amazon Rds MySql: adding read replica vs upgrading DB instance class

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am wondering if the following statements are right:

1. Both "adding read replica" and "upgrading DB instance class" improve read performance but result in difference cost and maintenance.
2. "upgrading DB instance class" improves also write performance.

Under https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/RDSMySQL
there is a tip

> You can add up to 5 read replicas to each database instance for
> enhanced read performance and increased availability. Read replicas
> can be Single-AZ or Multi-AZ, and can have the same or a different
> instance size as the database instance.
>
> Add each read replica to the AWS Pricing Calculator as an additional
> Amazon RDS for MySQL service.

While according to https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/
[image: Amazon RDS MySql Instance Class]
the prices of the next higher classes cost double the previous lower one.

It seems to me that upgrading to a higher class wins over adding a read replica (same price, additional write improvement) but I have no real experience with the matter so far.

Any hints, comments?

Comment: I forgot that the upgraded instance class must also be "Multi-AZ" to have the same availability as read replicas. In the above question, I should have asked if upgrading a DB instance from single-AZ to multi-AZ has same effect as adding read replicas.

Comment: I am currently in the same boat, did you come to a final conclusion?

Comment: Regarding multi- AZ deployments: "Multi-AZ deployments are not a read scaling solution, you cannot use a standby replica to serve read traffic. Multi-AZ maintains a standby replica for HA/failover." https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/02/amazon-rds-multi-az-deployments-read-replicas/

Comment: It's correct that, previously, the standby of an RDS Multi-AZ instance was not readable. However, more recently, Amazon have launched a Multi-AZ 'deployment'/cluster option with two readable standbys: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/03/amazon-rds-multi-az-transaction-commit-latency/